# Type Children Element is missing properties with Nextjs + React Context with TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

Using Reacts Context with Nextjs and TypeScript is showing a vague error wrapping context around the `_app.tsx`.

Event though I am passing in the values to the Context Provider it's giving me the error:

"Type '{ children: Element; }' is missing the following properties from type 'ContextProps': capturedPokemons, catchPokemon, releasePokemon"

Here is my `_app.tsx`

```js
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  return (
    <CaughtProvider>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </CaughtProvider>
  );
}
```

Here is the Context:

```js
type PokemonProps = {
  number: string;
  name: string;
  image: string;
};

type ContextProps = {
  capturedPokemons: PokemonProps[];
  catchPokemon: (newPokemon: PokemonProps[]) => void;
  releasePokemon: (id: string) => void;
};

const CaughtContext = createContext<ContextProps>({
  capturedPokemons: [],
  catchPokemon: () => undefined,
  releasePokemon: () => undefined,
});

export const useCaught = () => useContext(CaughtContext);

export const CaughtProvider: React.FC<ContextProps> = ({ children }) => {
  const [capturedPokemons, setCapturedPokemons] = useState<any>([]);

  const catchPokemon = (newPokemon: PokemonProps[]) => {
    if (capturedPokemons.length >= 6) {
      alert('You cannot carry any more Pokemon.');
      return;
    }

    const alreadyCaptured = capturedPokemons.some(
      (p: PokemonProps) => p.name === newPokemon[0].name
    );

    if (alreadyCaptured) {
      alert('you already have that pokemon');
      return;
    }

    if (window.confirm('Capture Pokemon')) {
      setCapturedPokemons([...capturedPokemons, ...newPokemon]);
    }
  };

  return (
    <CaughtContext.Provider
      value={{ catchPokemon, capturedPokemons, releasePokemon }}>
      {children}
    </CaughtContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

The app works fine as expected and as I'm aware this is how it's done in plain React/JS without TypeScript.

Answer (score 3):

You need to have a separate type for the `CaughtProvider`

```
type CaughtProviderProps = {
children: React.ReactNode
}
```

and use it as

```
CaughtProvider: React.FC<CaughtProviderProps>
```

`ContextProps` is for your `context value` so its not right to use it for `CaughtProvider` . `CaughtProvider` is just a component which takes the `children` prop . So its better to have a separate type for it .